# python - adding rows to an existing worksheet table

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm working with the .xlsx file and it has a tab with a workhsheet table where lots of conditional formatting are used. From time to time I need to append this table with new rows. 
My plan is to use python openpyxl (or other package) to append this table. 
so far I could identify this table as

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbood(myfile)
ws=wb['mytab']
tab = wb.ws._tables[0]
```

Can I use something like .append() method or change data of this table to add more rows to it? 
My goal is to keep the formatting.

I've already tried this approach - 
[Manipulate existing excel table using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657867/manipulate-existing-excel-table-using-openpyxl) and it doesn't' work for me

I'm using openpyxl 2.6.1

Regards,
Pavel

Comment: You just need to change the `ref` on the table.

Comment: I tried it. How to deal with style then? I need to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

## update "table.ref" to max row

```py
# ws - work sheet
row_num = ws.max_row + 1
table.ref[:-1] + str(row_num)  # A1:W98
```

## add new row data

```py
row_data = [1,2,3,4,5,]
for col, value in enumerate(row_data):
    ws.cell(row=row, column=col+1).value = value
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb=load_workbood(myfile)
ws=wb['mytab']
tab = ws.tables["Table1"]
tab.ref = f"A1:{ws.max_column}{ws.max_row}"
```

Comment: Please provide some context to your answer so that others can easily understand you approach to solve the problem.

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.

Answer (score -2):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filename= r'C:\Users\PC/test.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb['Hoja1']
ws["A1"] = "AAA"
ws["A2"] = "BBB"

wb.save(filename)
```