# Taking data from SQL Server and updating existing Excel sheet while keeping table possible?

Tags: python, excel, ssms

I have been trying to write a program that runs a SQL query then takes the data from that SQL query updates an existing Excel sheet while keeping/updating a chart in Python.

Is this possible?  I haven't been able to find any existing questions regarding this so I am sorry if this is a repeat.

**
For example, I have an items table with three items of varying quantities.  I can get the items to appear in my Excel sheet -- but any graph/chart I make is discarded once new information is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into this python package
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

You'll find ways to generate charts from python in your excel file.

Other possibility is to have your data go into a table in excel (not a range but an actual table)

you can follow the logic in this post for more information on how to achieve this
[Manipulate existing excel table using openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48657867/manipulate-existing-excel-table-using-openpyxl/48660854?noredirect=1#comment96993693_48660854)

Comment: Oh thank you!  I was using pandas and couldn't get what I needed to work.

Comment: Ahh, i believe that Pandas to_excel function overwrites the existing excel sheet with a new sheet, so that would explain your situation.